# I'm getting no preview available message when try to Open online PDF file in webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview

my code like this 
WebView webview = new WebView(getActivity());

```
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

   final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading", "Please wait...", true);
    progDailog.setCancelable(false);


    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

//        webview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
//following lines are to show the loader untile downloading the pdf file for view.
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            progDailog.show();
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url)
        {
            progDailog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    try {
        String urlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(pdf, "UTF-8");
        pdf = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + urlEncoded;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   String pdf = "http://192.168.2.154:8080/streamline/res/INV-000015.pdf";
    webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Answer (score 1):

`192.168.2.154` is a machine on your local network. `docs.google.com` cannot access it. `docs.google.com` can only access public URLs on public IP addresses.

Perhaps you might consider [other options for viewing PDFs](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html).

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can't access the pdf because you are using a local ip for the pdf. Try deploying it to a public domain and it should work just fine. You might consider other options like
**`Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdfLink));
            startActivity(browserIntent);`** but carefull ,this sollution might not work properly on lower versions of android bellow 7. I had some problems with samsung devices especially using default browser like samsung internet.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...What i did was that i parsed the url as Uri before concatenating it with the url and everything worked. Below is my code:

```
// sets visibility to visible
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


// displaying document in webview
String url = Uri.encode(fileUrl);


document_viewer.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
document_viewer.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
document_viewer.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
document_viewer.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
//document_viewer.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
// loads documentUrl into webView
document_viewer.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url);

document_viewer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        // sets visibility to visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here
        // sets visibility of progressBar to gone
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // sets visibility of webView to visible
        document_viewer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // setting the details of document on text Views
        title.setText(" Title : " + documentTitle);
        tag.setText(" Tag : " + documentTag);
        type.setText(" Type : " + documentType);
        comment.setText(" Comment : " + documentComment);
        distributee.setText(" Distributee : "  + documentDistributee);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                String description, String failingUrl) {
        view.loadUrl("about:blank");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.error_occurred), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }

});
```

Hope it helps. Thank you